# Several input fields with JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I wonder if it's possible to have several input fields i the JOptionPane in Java, instead of one like in the code below?

```
String info = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name?");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this...

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class OptionPaneTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);
    myPanel.add(field1);
    myPanel.add(field2);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, myPanel);
    System.out.println(field1.getText() + field2.getText());
}
}
```

Comment: please don't mix AWT with Swing, please to Amend that

Comment: Yes, thanks, though any example from any site shopuld be taken with a grain of salt. Consider the official Google example of using UiBinder with handwritten HTML in GWT :-)

Comment: Nice, I study a beginners course in Java and we haven't done any object oriented programming yet, so your code is a little bit hard to understand. I guess it would be possible to simplify in some way?

Comment: @3D-kreativ I don't think that it can be reasonably simplified, but I'll try. From the other side UI programming is really not the best thing to start with OOP.

Comment: @3D-kreativ wow, I have managed to write it with no OOP at all ;-)

Comment: That was very kind of you! Thanks! I will test the code tomorrow!

Comment: I've noticed a lot of the type of formatting used in your code, just over the last couple of weeks.  What I mean is that whereas I'd expect the `main()` o be indented, it is not.  What tool are you using to edit code?  Is there a name for that type of code indentation?

Comment: I just use Eclipse. However to highlight code on SO every line should have indentation of 4 spaces. So I just paste code here and than insert 4 spaces in every line that does not have them. Surely this can be done better, but it seemed to me that all is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can in fact show a very complex GUI with JLabels, JButtons, JTextFields, JTextAreas, and all sorts of other goodies, all displayed in a simple to call [JOptionPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input). I don't think I'd use the `showInputDialog(...)` method for this though.